# Get .htaccess to show .index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make my `.htaccess` file show the `index.php` of a subfolder without having it displayed in the URL bar but I'm a noob with `.htaccess`.

This is what I want ...

Full Path: `http://example.com/pages/games/demons-souls/index.php`

URL Path: `http://example.com/games/demons-souls/`

So far I've managed to get it to show `http://example.com/games/demons-souls/index`

Strange enough it works when I don't hide the *pages* subdirectory in the URL, e.g.

```
http://example.com/pages/games/demons-souls/
```

My `.htaccess` file looks like this ...

```
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# H I D E - P H P - E X T E N S I O N

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

# H I D E - F O L D E R : P A G E S

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pages/games
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)$ pages/games/$1 [L]

# R E D I R E C T - I N D E X - ? ? ?
```

I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: Are you using extensionless URLs in other parts of your site? In your example, this is not required. In your example you are just requesting a directory and expecting `index.php` to be served from that directory - is that the case with all your URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Your directives are in the wrong order. Your second rule is *unconditional* (`RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows). However, if you are enforcing a trailing slash on your URLs then presumably these don't map to files anyway? Although you have enabled MultiViews, which is essentially making your directives that handle extensionless URLs redundant.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable always starts with a slash so your *condition* (that checks against `!^pages/games` - no slash prefix) will always be successful.

Try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "/games/<anything>" to "/pages/games/<anything>"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/games
RewriteRule ^games($|/.*) pages/$0 [L]

# This may not be required...
# Rewrite extensionless URLs to ".php" if they exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

The above will internally rewrite a request for `/games/demons-souls/` to `/pages/games/demons-souls/`. mod_dir will then issue an internal subrequest for `index.php` (the `DirectoryIndex` document) - there is nothing extra you need to add for this to work.

In the example you've given you don't actually need the second rule that handles extensionless URLs. (?) Note that your directive implies that your extensionless URLs all end in a trailing slash. For example, `/games/demon-souls/foo/` would be internally rewritten to `/pages/games/demon-souls/foo.php` if that file exists.

> Strange enough it works when I don’t hide the pages subdirectory in the URL, e.g.
>
> ```
> http://example.com/pages/games/demons-souls/
> ```

In that scenario you aren't using your `.htaccess` directives at all. When you request a physical directory then mod_dir searches for the `DirectoryIndex` document (ie. `index.php`) in that directory and serves it if found.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you so much for your time and effort to explain it to me (even though I think I have to read it a couple more times). The rewriting works as intended now. 

However, I would actually like to hide the .php extension from URLs. Could you tell me what would be the best solution for this?

Comment: @BorisBär To clarify, with regards to the "hiding of the `.php` extension", have you already removed the file extension from your internal links?

Comment: Yes, I did! Actually I managed to do it with this additional snippet and by activating MultiViews: 
`# Remove .php extension from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php`

Comment: @BorisBär "by activating MultiViews" - You should _not_ enable MultiViews here (if you are using mod_rewrite to perform additional rewrites - as you are doing). I explicitly disabled MultiViews in my answer for this reason. By enabling MultiViews, the mod_rewrite rule(s) (that append the extension) are effectively overridden so are not actually doing anything - this will likely cause conflicts in the future when you need to make changes.